# Looping Syntax within Formula

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, vba

In my macro, I want to loop within formulas:

```
    Range("D4").Formula = "=Inputs!D8
```

transforms successfully to:

```
    For i = 1 To 5
    Range("D4").Formula = "=Inputs!D" & i + 7
```

I want to do the same for the code below:

```
 Range("G4").Formula = "=IF($C4<=Inputs!$E$8+Portfolio_Duration-1,SUM($H4:$DC4),"""")"
```

I tried

```
    For i = 1 To 5        
    Range("G4").Formula = "=IF($C4<=Inputs!$E$" & i + 7+Portfolio_Duration-1,SUM($H4:$DC4),"""")"
```

But I am getting a compile error:
Expected: end of statement.

Could you please assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,

```
Range("G4").Formula = "=IF($C4<=Inputs!$E$" & i + 7 + Portfolio_Duration - 1 & ",SUM($H4:$DC4),"""")"
```

You are missing a `"` and a `&`